# How i can Open CMD.exe from my iis website C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webmethod

I need to Run CMD.exe using Web Method; I use

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe", "MyText");
```

that works if I use View in Browser, but when I connect my website using Browser localhost:// (use iis) that does not work.

Comment: You can't start a process on the client from a web server. Imagine what malicious websites would do if you could.

Comment: @CodeCaster How did you conclude from the question that this has anything to do with running a process on the client side?

Comment: @KobyDouek based on the text under the code. It works from Visual Studio, so they claim, but doesn't work from localhost (by which I assume they mean IIS).

Comment: @CodeCaster I disagree. It runs in debug mode, but not after deployment. Classic case of an incorrect hardcoded path.

Comment: @Koby no, it runs just fine. It's just that IIS runs as a service on desktop 0, so you won't see the console window. The command prompt is started on the server, not on the client.

Comment: I use Visual Studio,, active iis to run my website on Browser

Comment: How do you tell it 'works' - please explain? Does it do something that you can use to test?

Comment: I just view my code using (View in Browser) and no problem this statement open CMD,,

Comment: When I connected using IIS to Open it from Browser Directly (using localhost:Port) it dose not work,, that is!